# Application process not visible in Eclipse Devices section

Tags: android

[image]
Facing some problem. When I connect my device to USB, under Devices section my device is visible. But when I am starting my application on device, my application process is not visible under device. It was visible till yesterday. Today it is not visible, so m not able to see my application logs in Eclipse.

If I run some another application then its process is visible. Only problem with my application.

What may be the reason of such behavior?

Adding screenshot of eclipse. My application process is not visible below android.process.acore. when I run my application. I have created a filter to see my application logs only and I am not able to see logs now.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that android debug bridge is not working, which happens for me every now and then. You can try this:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```